# What are 'Uno Packages'?

Tags: openoffice

I found several 'uno_packages' folders on my PC. Searching the web, I find several mentions of uno packages, but I can't find a definition or description.

Answer (score 1):

An UNO package can take several forms. Typically what you put into the uno_packages folder is a zip file. This zip file may be contained within the zip file that you download, along with other documentation.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Uno

UNO stands for Universal Network Objects